# Spyder 5 Won't Launch on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I just migrated my Python environment to a new laptop and am having trouble launching Spider 5. I am using Python 3.7 and have tried to launch via Anaconda Navigator and the command prompt. Here is the error I get:

```
(DS7331) C:\Users\BNayd>spyder
C:\Users\BNayd\anaconda3\envs\DS7331\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\image_path_manager.py:46: UserWarning: The icon located in C:\Users\BNayd\anaconda3\envs\DS7331\lib\site-packages\spyder\images\dark\kite.svg is overriding the existing kite
  f'The icon located in {complete_path} is overriding '
No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied. You have to call load_stylesheet function after instantiation of QApplication to take effect.
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 5x13+640+280 on QWidgetWindow/'QLabelClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  120x13+640+280 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 5x13+640+280 on QWidgetWindow/'QLabelClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  120x13+640+280 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 5x13+640+280 on QWidgetWindow/'QLabelClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  120x13+640+280 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 5x13+640+280 on QWidgetWindow/'QLabelClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  120x13+640+280 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BNayd\anaconda3\envs\DS7331\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1058, in <lambda>
    lambda c=client: self.process_started(c))
  File "C:\Users\BNayd\anaconda3\envs\DS7331\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1733, in process_started
    self.main.variableexplorer.add_shellwidget(client.shellwidget)
  File "C:\Users\BNayd\anaconda3\envs\DS7331\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\plugin.py", line 113, in add_shellwidget
    self.get_widget().add_shellwidget(shelwidget)
  File "C:\Users\BNayd\anaconda3\envs\DS7331\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\main_widget.py", line 537, in add_shellwidget
    self._set_actions_and_menus(nsb)
  File "C:\Users\BNayd\anaconda3\envs\DS7331\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\main_widget.py", line 710, in _set_actions_and_menus
    editor.insert_action_above = QAction()
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QAction(QObject): not enough arguments
  QAction(str, QObject): not enough arguments
  QAction(QIcon, str, QObject): not enough arguments
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1260x1840+18+41 on QWidgetWindow/'MainWindowClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  1260x1061+18+41 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 485x314, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).
```

How can I remedy this issue?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That error message is caused by a bug in Spyder and it'll be fixed in our next version (5.0.1), to be released shortly.

The only workaround for now is to open the Anaconda Prompt (or a system terminal like `cmd.exe` on Windows, `Terminal` on macOS, or `xterm` on Linux) and run there:

`spyder --reset`

Comment: I downgraded to Spyder 4.2.5 and it still does the same thing. I get the initial launch window but then it crashes.

Comment: Hi, I also have the same issue. When I launch using Spyder Icon, it says "Initializing" and doesn't do anything further.  When I launch using "spyder" from the Anaconda prompt, it works. When I launch using the Navigator, it works.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall.
2. Delete al cache and residual files of spyder, look in appdata folder.
3. Reinstall.

Spyder is an amazing and agile IDE but sometimes is a pain in the ass.